# docker cannot run awscli commands

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am trying to build a docker image that runs some `awscli` commands but I am having trouble doing so. This is running on jenkins. I have added my security credentials to `~/.aws/credentials`. My credentials file contains this:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = 1234567890
aws_secret_access_key = abcdeffhikjkndasjk123123455
```

when i run my command it says its complete,

```
RUN aws s3 sync s3://test-bucket/file.txt /opt
 sha256:123456789
 DONE 1.2s
```

but when I got to check whats in the directory, the file is not there

```
RUN ls -la /opt
#18 0.374 drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            29 May 11 11:10 .
#18 0.374 drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            17 May 11 11:10 ..
#18 0.374 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root           125 May 11 11:09 otherfiles.txt
```

This is what I have in my dockerfile so far:

```
WORKDIR ~/.aws/
COPY credentials .
COPY config .
RUN echo $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION

WORKDIR /opt

RUN aws s3 sync s3://test-bucket/file.txt /opt
RUN ls -la /opt
```

how can I troubleshoot and fix this?

Comment: I'd expect this to work mechanically, but it compromises your AWS credentials by publishing them into the image, and it will be unsuccessful if your environment requires you to assume an AWS role to do things.  Can you run the `aws` command on the host, before you `docker build` the image, and then just `COPY` the file from the host system?

Comment: add `RUN aws s3 ls`  after `WORKDIR /opt`  for debugging